# Can't open Wired Settings

Tags: nvidia, network-manager, wired

Fresh install of Ubuntu 22 LTS with NVIDIA card.
When I try to open Wired Settings it won't open and log goes wild with NVIDIA-DRM errors.

```
Nov  4 20:11:32 ubuntu22 kernel: [539792.105809] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership Nov  4 20:11:32 ubuntu22 kernel: [539792.106608] gnome-control-c[1144248] segfault at 0 ip 00007f270d7a1ab0 sp 00007ffcab70eb70 error 4 in libc.so.6[7f270d782000+195000] likely on CPU 5 (core 1, socket 0)
```

How and why is NVIDIA Ubuntu driver connected to Wired Settings?